# What is the limitations and advantages of Cross Compiler for C# to java?

Tags: java, c#-4.0, cross-platform

I want to migrate my entire C# 4.0(.Net 2010) desktop Application to Java.I don't know any tool available for that?Please suggest me good one.

Also, i would like to know what are the limitations and advantages of Cross Compiler for C# to java?

please guide me to get out of this problem...

Saravanan.P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crosscompilers will usually produce rather messy code, and sometimes code that doesn't even compile.
Some (maybe most) will force your new code into having bindings with custom libraries from the crosscompiler, and thus be forever linked to that product.

Your new code will be very hard to maintain and expand as a result, and might well offer poor performance as well as compared to the old code when compiled.

In general, you would most likely be better off rewriting the application yourself (or hiring people to do so) if it is going to have to be used and maintained actively for more than a short, transitional period.

That said, for some things a crosscompiler can be helpful. For example start with a crosscompiled version and over time replace that codebase with newly written code, this would get you working more quickly and you'd not have to maintain 2 separate code bases, in 2 different languages, using 2 toolsets, at the same time.